# saving and loading compressed R object

Tags: r

```
save(something, file="something.RData", compress="xz")
```

then when I load for reuse

```
load("something.RData")

print(something)

Error in print(something) : object 'something' not found
```

It is a random forest object.
Am I missing the unzip code?

Comment: What happens if you try to load with `load("something.RData", verbose = TRUE)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works at the console (where you have no parent environment), but not in a function because of the way `load()` uses environments (and will assign to the calling function).

Two simple alternatives:

1. Use `saveRDS()` and `readRDS()` for single objects.
2. Create an environment and use it as shown below.

Here is a short example of the second approach:

```
ne <- new.env()
load(somefile, ne)   # now ls(ne) will show what was loaded
foo <- ne$something
```

Comment: I must have misunderstood your answer, it seems to work fine for me? Hansi@Hansi:~$ echo "something <- 1:5;save(something,file=\"something.RData\",compress=\"xz\");rm(something);load(\"something.RData\");print(something)" > script.r
hansi@Hansi:~$ Rscript "script.r" > out
hansi@Hansi:~$ cat out
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
but I tend to use the environment method or get(load("blah.RData"))

Comment: Ooops.  That should have said _function_ where it said _script_. Thanks for catching that, now corrected.